# Selected ListItem in Datasource not Selected after DataBinding

Tags: vb.net, drop-down-menu

I'm selecting a ListItem as I add it to a ListItemCollection.  Then I use that ListItemCollection as a datasource for a DropDownlist but the Selected List Item is not being selected after databind.  Here is an example of the code:

```
ListItemCollection items = new ListItemCollection();
ListItem item;
item = new ListItem("Option 1", "1");
items.Add(item);
item = new ListItem("Option 2", "2");
item.Selected = true;
items.Add(item);
ddl1.DataSource = items;
ddl1.DataBind();
```

I'm trying to get this to work so I can return only a list of items, instead of a list of items and the selected value.  Is there a way to make the DropDownList select the selected ListItem from the ListItemCollection (or any other type of collection)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm... this seems like a strange method to take for accomplishing this, you should be able to do something along these lines:

```
ddl1.Items.Clear();
foreach(ListItem item in items)
{
   ddl1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Which should solve your selection issue...

Comment: Hmm, that might be a good work around.  Why do you think this is a strange method to be using here?  What would you recommend?

Comment: I have just not run across anyone who binds a DropDownList to an ListItemCollection. Usually DropDownList would be bound do some other object that implemented IEnumberable

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can set the selected value before you bind to the drop down.  I think you have to do it after it has been bound.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the SelectedValue property of your DropDownList :

```
ddl1.SelectedValue = "Option 2";
```

Here I'm using a literal string, but it's best to the `item.Text` value to set it. You can use it before or after the `DataBind()`, it works either way.